# Swing How to identify which jbutton user is clicking

Tags: java, jbutton

i am creating a seats researvation system in java.....i have created an array of jbuttons. Is there any way i can identify which button is clicked or maybe i can get the index of the button when it is clicked.

```
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
    btn1[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i+1));
    btn1[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 30));
    btn1[i].setBackground(Color.green);
    panel.add(btn1[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to distinguish which button fired the ActionEvent:

1. Set/get the action command of each button (eg if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Button Name"))
2. Use == to compare instances (eg if (e.getSource() == buttray[0] ))
3. Get the text of the JButton (eg if (e.getSource().getText().equals("Button Name"))
4. Set/get the name of the JButton (eg if (e.getSource().getName().equals("Button Name"))

In your case you have a name.. so #4 should work inside your buttton event

```
btn1[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    String bName = e.getSource().getText()
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much